# Mix long term caching and code splitting in webpack 2

Tags: javascript, caching, webpack, frontend, code-splitting

I'm writing a javascript webapp using webpack 2 as module bundler.

What I need is a way to mix long term caching feature (https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) and code splitting (https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/).

I'm able to lazy load a vendor library (pixi.js in my case) using require.ensure but this cause a bundle creation including the lib. I'm also able to create cachable bundles, but I would like to create a bundle for long term caching and use it in lazy loaded part.

Is it possible?

**Edit 1**

I add some parts of my config for a better explanation.

```
entry: {
  vendor: ['some', 'vendors', 'libs'],
  pixi: ['pixi.js'],
  main: ['babel-polyfill', './app/index.js'],
},
output: {
  [... other configuration]
  filename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js',
  chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
},
```

I'm using the vendor bundle for external libraries needed at startup time, but the pixi.js is only needed in some cases, but I would like to be long term cached.

The bundling phase emit this 2 files (and many others):

`pixi.8ef3aeac142f1bf921bf.bundle.js`
`6.9331d810904191781167.js`

their content is almost the same. The second one is created by the require.ensure but I would like the `pixi.8ef3aeac142f1bf921bf.bundle.js` was used.

Comment: question: why you need `pixi` bundle? If you are load the pixi component with require.ensure is already provided by the `6.9331d810904191781167.js`. You do not need to declare a bundle for it.

Comment: I would like to enable long term caching and I'm not sure that the "6." part of the chunk filename will remain the same if I add other require.ensure.

Comment: Ok I am updating the existing answer then. Look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `require.ensure` produce a different code chunk that will be built in a different file. The kind of cache you want to offer is about the naming policy you give to those bundles (and your server configuration of course).

The parameter you are looking for is *chunckFilename*.

```
output: {
  chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
}
```

If you set it like this you will always have predeterminated chuncks named `0.chunk.js`, `1.chunk.js`, etc..

Of course that can pose a problem for clients, so you would like to configure this parameter as follows:

```
output: {
  chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js',
}
```

Adding **chunkhash** to the name of your chunk will give you `0.4c473bca1d7688737499.chunk.js`, `1.2cfbf4a9cc0e1f24ec2c.chunk.js`, etc kind of chunk names.

The chunkhash is identical for each application build that doesn't change the chunck code. That means that if you never change your library, the chunkhash will never change, thus the user will never have to re-download that file again.

If you want to **ensure the chunk to always have the same name**, then you can specify the name on the `require.ensure` declaration:

```
require.ensure([], function(require){
  var pixi = require('pixi');
  // ...
}, "pixi"); // this will be passed webpack template under [name] and can be used with chunkFilename
```

I personally suggest the same approach for bundles naming:

```
output: {
  /**
   * Specifies the name of each output file on disk.
   * IMPORTANT: You must not specify an absolute path here!
   *
   * See: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-filename
   */
  filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js',

  /** The filename of non-entry chunks as relative path
   * inside the output.path directory.
   *
   * See: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/#output-chunkfilename
   */
  chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js',
}
```

Comment: I have an almost identical configuration but is not what I'm looking for. I'll try to edit my answer with some config snippets.

Comment: @c3s4 I have updated the answer with the example of how to name your chunk

Comment: sorry for thi late answer. It works perfectly for what I need.
Thanks